# How come Ser Loras is engaged to Cersei after being in the Kingsguard?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* we know that Jaime cannot marry, as Kingsguard members are supposed to not have family, as they took the oath to protect the king. I believe this oath is the same like the people at the Wall take.

On the other hand, we see Ser Loras Tyrell was supposed to get married to Sansa or Cersei, while he was Kingsguard for Renly and I believe he is Kingsguard for Joffrey and Tommen. Isn't he supposed to be bound with such an oath?

Comment: I don't think Ser Lorar ever was a sworn kingsguard for anyone, especially not for the official king Joffrey/Tommen as part of the official kingsguard in King's Landing.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Sorry for confusion, he was part of Rainbow gaurd (kingsguard of Renly) , but he is dead and never  actually sit on Iron throne so that vow doesn't matter in tv series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike the books, Ser Loras is not part of King Joffrey's Kingsguard, and this status has not changed with the advent of King Tommen. He was indeed part of King Renly's Kingsguard, but with Renly's death, his vows were not renewed to Joffrey. This was a change in the story since in the TV universe he is the only Tyrell son, unlike the books where he was the third son.

Comment: Does this mean in the books he's not arranged to marry Cersei?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Yes. In fact, Neither he nor Cersei are engaged to *anyone*. In the books, the Tyrells planned to wed Sansa to the Tyrell heir Ser Willas, but then the Lannisters intervened.

Comment: Thanks @SystemDown i read book last year and watching season 5 now , I am mixing both stories in my mind

Comment: @Panther - Just so you know, the show runners have confirmed that they are officially diverging from the books in terms of story.

Comment: @SystemDown yes in season 4 they started mixing 2 characters as book have many characters. And now Season 5 is totally different. Need to have to parallel slot in mind to keep book and tv series story

Answer (score -2):

Sansa was actually engaged to the Tyrell heir, Ser Willas, but then Cersei was like "lol no" and married her to Tyrion. Cersei was never engaged to Loras. And Loras was only part of the rainbow guard, which only served Renly. Fun fact, Renly and Loras were both gay lovers.

Comment: The Wilas involvement was only in the books, he doesn't appear in the TV series.